# What significance can we assign to 'breathing' of $s$-shell orbitals?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atomic-physics, orbitals, spherical-harmonics

In my atomic lecture notes it says

> We can visualise an $l=0$ $s$-state as a spherical cloud expanding and contracting - breathing, as the the electron moves in space.

Similarly in the video [enter link description here](https://youtu.be/Ziz7t1HHwBw?t=142)

it has an animation of the spherical harmonic growing and contracting in time.

How much can we read into these description of the orbitals - can we therefore infer that there is only intrinsic 'radial' motion for the electron in s-orbitals and hence they have $l=0$? Or are these results of the oscillations of the spherical harmonics in time unphysical since they are only in $\psi$ and not $|\psi|^2$?

Comment: What *exactly* do the spheres in that video represent? s-orbitals are stationary states of a hydrogen-like atom, and so their only time evolution is an overall phase, so I don't think it is reasonable to think of them as 'breathing in and out'

Comment: That video is *extremely* misleading - pending a detailed look, I would say: stay well away from it. Atomic eigenstates are stationary, and they don't evolve in time at all.

Comment: That video addresses *spherical harmonics* in general, *not* spherical harmonics as applied to quantum mechanics.   Spherical harmonics describe the *angular* geometry of a system and say nothing about the radial geometry.   In general, the radial geometry of a system can change ("breath") and still be described by the same spherical harmonic.  But in quantum mechanics *the radial behavior is fixed*.   There is no breathing.

Comment: I so wish text books wouldn't come up with that kind of crap!

Comment: @garyp - I think what you're saying makes sense, but as a bonus question, for the electron states with orbital angular momentum, their wavefunction gains a phase which makes it rotate azimuthally over time (even if this isnt true for the wavefunction squared). Can we interpret this rotation as somehow physical?

Comment: After all, we do get a non-zero probability current.

Comment: @BySymmetry to the extent that $e^{iE_0t/\hbar} = \cos{iE_0t/\hbar} + i\sin{iE_0t/\hbar}$, $Re{\psi}$ and $Im{\psi}$ are breathing out of phase...the question is "where" are they breathing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That video was about spherical modes of vibration, so these modes are certainly present (approximately, as the earth is not a sphere) in the the Earth after a large earthquake, or in a spherical ballon that is driven into oscillation.

Before jumping to atomic orbitals, consider what the video did: it took waves on a string, and imagined them on a spherical surface.

So let's consider waves on a string and the modes of the particle in an infinite well. The fundamental mode of a string vibrates up and down, meanwhile, the ground state of a particle in a box looks like:

$$ \psi_1(x) \propto \sin{\pi x/L} $$

Does that mean the electron is vibrating up and down? No. $\psi(x)$ doesn't even vibrate in the vertical direction...there is no vertical direction. The particle in a box has but one dimension, $x$.

The reason they look the same is because the functions are solving the same (or extremely similar) wave equations, but in atomic orbitals, $Y_l^m(\theta, \phi)$ is by no means describing a radial excitation, or a physical oscillation in any direction.

Addendum:

So if look at a state like $|l=n, m=n\rangle$, the angular and time dependence is:

$$ \sin^n{\theta}e^{+ni\phi}e^{-i\omega t}= \sin^n{\theta}e^{i(n\phi-\omega t)}$$

which describes an equatorial wave going around in the "north" direction. Of course:

$$ ||\psi||^2 \propto \sin^{2n}{\theta} $$

is stationary, but the probability current is non-zero.

Note that all the "motion" is occurring in the complex phase, and not in the probability distribution. This is also true of plane waves.

I've noticed that most serious youtube videos devoted to $\psi$ do not show that the action is in the complex part of the wave function, rather, they show an bulge in $x$ moving around, or a real wave oscillating through zero. Wave-packets should be imagined more like a cork screw..the real and imaginary projections go though zero, but the magnitude of the wave function does not.

Appreciating this nuance is key to understanding why $\hat {\bf p} = -i/\hbar{\bf \nabla}$ and the energy dependence goes like $\exp{(-iE/\hbar)}$.

Comment: I think what you're saying makes sense, but as a bonus question, for the electron states with orbital angular momentum, their wavefunction gains a phase which makes it rotate azimuthally over time (even if this isnt true for the wavefunction squared). Can we interpret this rotation as somehow physical? After all, we do get a non-zero probability current.

Comment: @AlexGower think of the similar picture of eigenfunctions of the momentum operator: they are also constant everywhere in space, and their phase also moves along the direction of the momentum. But it would be wrong to think that the phase speed has any relation to the expectation value of absolute speed of the electron. E.g. it depends on the reference zero point of energy (which is arbitrary!). What you can actually do is try to introduce an envelope over this complex exponential to get a _wave packet_, and see that it moves on average with _group speed_.

Comment: Ah okay, is there any itnerpretation at all to be made about phase speed?

Answer (score 2):

As I write there are several answers saying (correctly) that there is no breathing motion of the S states in an atom (I prefer the word 'state' to 'orbital' here). However, in such a state the electron does have kinetic energy, and the only contribution to that energy is from radial motion. So then the question arises, can we offer any further intuition about this motion? This is what the 'breathing' idea is intended to do, I think, but I think it mostly gives a misleading impression.

The main intuition you need here is that of a standing wave. A standing wave can have kinetic energy without going anywhere overall. A standing wave can also be thought of as a sum of travelling waves going in different directions. In this example that motion is purely radial: going in, going out, simultaneously, in a superposition. The net effect is that the probability density $|\psi|^2$ is entirely static, but the kinetic energy $\langle \hat{\bf p}^2 / 2m \rangle$ is non-zero.

Finally, I note that in some answers people offer the picture of a smeared-out electron, and in others it is said you don't have a smeared-out electron but a point-like one, and the wavefunction represents a statistical ensemble. These viewpoints are not mutually contradictory, and neither of them is completely right or wrong. They are just offering guides to our intuition. To get a statement which is clearly right or wrong you have to talk about an unambiguously measurable quantity such as a probability of a given event, or the value of an expectation value. Here the probability distribution for finding the electron at one place or another is spherically symmetric and static, and the expectation value of the kinetic energy operator is non-zero.

You can also find observable quantities which show the wavelike nature of the wavefunction itself. For that you could, for example, study what happens when the state is a superposition of two different energy eigenstates. It could for example be a superposition of $s$ states with different values of principle quantum number $n$. In the latter case you get a breathing motion in the probability density.

Answer (score 1):

The video you give is talking about the appearance of the spherical harmonics in a different context from their appearance in atomic orbitals: it refers to their appearance as describing vibrations on a spherical, but two-dimensional, *surface* made of an idealized elastic material. The spherical harmonics that appear in atomic orbitals are mathematically the same, but the signification is quite different. There are analogies, but they are not a complete 1:1.

For one, while this surface is only two-dimensional, atomic orbitals occupy a whole spatial *volume* - they are actually three-dimensional. For another, there are composite orbital states that do not have any analogue to the vibrations on the surface, owing to that extra degree of freedom provided by the third dimension.

And those differences carry over into motion. While the elastic membrane does indeed flex, atomic orbitals actually do not change their shape at all.

That said, in their case, there *is* what one can think of as a sort of "subtler" motion suggested by the quantum equation. This subtle motion takes the form of the "beating" or throbbing, *not* of the shape, but of the *phase*, that is generated by the action of the Hamiltonian operator: for the orbital $|n,l,m\rangle$,

$$|\psi\rangle(t) = |n,l,m\rangle\ e^{iE_nt/\hbar}$$

where $E_n$ is the energy. The angular velocity of the subtle vibration is $E_n/\hbar$, and the frequency that corresponds to this is $|E_n|/h$.

This vibration is *unobservable* directly for an individual orbital, *but* it absolutely matters if you consider cases in which two or more orbitals can interfere with each other, which suggests it has some sort of physical realism, but of a kind not directly accessible to us. Hence why I call it, *subtle motion*.

Moreover, to further underline the differences here with the elastic case, because the total energies $E_n$ are negative, but increase (become less negative) with increasing principal quantum number $n$, this creates the interesting result that high-energy orbitals throb *slower* than low-energy ones, which is exactly the *opposite* of the *perceptible* vibration of the elastic surface, which beats *more* vigorously at higher-energy modes. For example, the $n = 1$ ground state of hydrogen throbs at about 3290 THz, while both states in the $n = 2$ excited *family* throb at only 1/4 this frequency, or about 823 THz, and the $n = 3$ family, at 366 THz.

The most interesting part about this motion is that its frequency is actually exactly twice that of the classical Kepler orbit with the given energy and angular momentum under the electric force. This suggests a possible interpretation, under the "quantum theory as a theory of systems with limited information content" paradigm[1], that this is the actual underlying movement of the electron, but there physically is no information giving what the true anomaly is, so the probability distribution of position doesn't track it and thus is static, as well as there being no information as to whether the orbit is even going clockwise or counterclockwise, which secondarily accounts for the factor of two in the frequency, because effectively, oppositional points of the orbit have become identified.

---

[1] for some preceding work on this direction, see https://www.perimeterinstitute.ca/videos/quantum-mechanics-theory-systems-limited-information-content

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a nice interpretation. It may be easier to understand what's going on in the simpler example of a particle in a box, in one dimension. Consider the lowest-energy standing wave of this system, which is a wave where half a wavelength fits in the box. If you apply the de Broglie relation $p=h/\lambda$, you get a momentum. This seems paradoxical, since momentum suggests movement, but this is a standing wave, so there is no probability flux to the left or right. But actually the de Broglie relation only tells us the magnitude of the momentum, not its sign. Recall from your study of waves that a standing wave can be considered as a superposition of two traveling waves going in opposite directions.

The ground state of hydrogen is the same story, just with a little more complication because it's in three dimensions. Conceptually, it's the same idea. There is no probability flux because it's a standing wave. However, there is "motion" in the sense that this state is not a state with a definite value of momentum p=0.

> How much can we read into these description of the orbitals - can we therefore infer that there is only intrinsic 'radial' motion for the electron in s-orbitals and hence they have =0?

Yes, there is only radial motion in the sense that the momentum operator in quantum mechanics is the gradient operator, and this wavefunction only has a gradient in the radial direction.

> Or are these results of the oscillations of the spherical harmonics in time unphysical since they are only in  and not |ψ|2?

Actually you can make the oscillations go away completely just by redefining the zero level of potential energy in such a way that the state you're considering has a total energy of zero.

You just have to accept the idea that in quantum mechanics, there can be "motion without motion" -- that is, motion when no physical observable is changing over time. A simpler example is a plane wave.

Comment: *But actually the de Broglie relation only tells us the magnitude of the momentum, not its sign.* So how come the momentum operator returns an imaginary number?

Answer (score 0):

A useful picture for the electronic $s$-orbits ($L=0$ states) in an atom is that the electron is oscillating through the center of the nucleus. However, we are not considering a single oscillation in one preferred direction, but we average the oscillations of all possible directions in 3D. This results in a spherical probability distribution with zero angular momentum, $L=0$. However, there is no "breathing" of the orbit involved -- at least not on a time scale on the order of $1ns$.

Comment: I think there will be some "breathing" if you take a suitable superposition of $s$-states with different $n$. Namely, in a radial probability plot this will look like a wave packet going back and forth.

Comment: @Ruslan: I believe the OP considers the "simple" atomic state, such as $1s$ and not a superposition of states with different $n$.

Answer (score 0):

> We can visualise an l=0 s-state as a spherical cloud expanding and
> contracting - breathing, as the the electron moves in space.

1. 'Spherical cloud' is often read and heared but is questionable, because Y=const. means const. angular probability density, i.e. the electron may have any angular value in an ensemble of equally prepared atoms. It does not mean that the azimuthal angle of an electron in a single atom is 'smeared' and forms a spherical cloud! This is a misunderstanding which is found very often.
2. The eigenvalues of the potential and the kinetic energy in the groundstate (n,l,m = 1,0,0) obeys the virial theorem: T = - V/2
   which means that the kinetic energy is repulsive and has half the Coulomb attractive potential energy V:
   V = - 27.2 eV and T = +13.6 eV. The textbooks say that V is only radial, V=V(r). In particular, the qm. eigenvalues of radial velocity are: v = 0 and v² != 0. Thus, indeed a radial oscillation of the electron can be deduced as a physical interpretation of the qm. wave model.